# associating git and trello-like solutions (wekan)

Tags: git, trello

I'm looking for advices/solutions as I'd like to manage card creation etc in wekan in association with git (not github), on a private network. I just wonder if something like that exists. I was thinking of using git hooks to use command line to do that, but maybe there's better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Git being local on your desktop, you would need a [post-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) to parse your commit message and update/close/reopen a [Wekan̈](https://wekan.github.io/) card.

The other option is to setup a local Git server like **[Gogs](https://gogs.io/)**: you would then benefit from a more complete integration, where opening an issue associated to your Git repository would open a Wekan̈ card: see "[**`wekan/wekan-gogs`**](https://github.com/wekan/wekan-gogs)"